# Deployment "JMSServerManager" is in error due to: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 127.0.0.1:1234

Tags: jms, hornetq

I was trying to set Hornetq clustors. I have one server and one backup server. I configured the configuration.xml as they mentioned in the user guide. But I'm not able to start the machine.

If anybody knows this,please help me.....
Thanks in advance.....:)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have both servers using the same IP. You should have different ones like 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2.

Also look at hornetq-beans for the jndi ip and port.